# open console (terminal) window and execute command (rsync) on os x

Tags: macos, backup

I am from a windows background and trying to help a mac user friend to backup her pictures, docs, etc. onto an external drive.  In windows, I would accomplish this by creating a simple batch file with an xcopy command and have a shortcut on the desktop that pointed to that .bat file when double clicked.  However, in the mac world I am having significant trouble finding how to do this.  I have searched repeatedly to find the mac equivalent, but all I find are sites saying things like "there are so many options on a mac - use one of them."  However, none have ever given a specific solution nor pointed to a specific solution.  Anyone here know of a specific step by step process to accomplish this?  I simply want to be able to have her double click an icon on the desktop and have it copy her personal documents (not application settings or other overhead) to her external hard drive.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the batch file, which is usually called a shell script.
2. Enter all the commands that you want to run.
3. Set the executable bit, this is done with chmod +x path-to-the-file in Terminal.
4. Show info for the script and set Terminal to the application which should open it.

However, what I've done in similar situations and that I would recommend that you do is that I've created a shell script and instead of using Terminal I've initiated it from an AppleScript application. You can of course embed the entire shell script in the AppleScript as well. Basically it will look something like the following:

```
on run
  do shell script "rsync -av ~/Pictures /Volume/Backup"
end run
```

Repeat the *do shell ...* line for each folder that you want to copy, or call the shell script itself. Then use AppleScript Editor which is included with Mac OS X and save it as an actual application.